# Can Pending HTLC's drop my balance?

Tags: security, client, balance, hash-time-locked-contract, time

I just noticed that 2 million sat's disappeared from my balance in thunderhub. No payments or transactions have been made. Can pending HTLC's effect my balance? If Not what else could drop my balance like that? My LND node has been up constantly for 4+ months and I never seen a drop like this that hasnt came back yet. (I usually see mild fluctuations.)I see about 7 htlcs sitting in pending. Thanks I'm still very new at this and appreciate any help. I lf it keeps dropping I hate to close all my channels, it's making me a little nervous.